# Power bi (Frontend) and Visual Studio (Cube & Backend)

Tags: visual-studio, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Disclaimer: I cannot post any screenshots as it's organization private data.

I am getting kind of error which is not related to any syntax

Scenario: In table (Order_Data) I have a column named as "creationWithCutoff" and there is data in that column and this column is made in Visual Studio 2019 and this column is being used by another column made in visual studio 2019 for some calculation (Dax is being used).

Here is the DAX query (Changed for Company's data policy purposes)

**=DIVIDE(ABS(DATEDIFF(Order_Data[order_time], Order_Data[CreationWithCutoff],SECOND)), 3600,0**)

*Note: Both the columns have updated data*

So, even after refreshing the table in the Cube (Cube made in Visual Studio 2019) the data is not showing up in Power bi even though the query is correct.

I have converted the Excel formula into Dax query

Excel Formula: =IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS('Order Data'!BF:BF,'Order Data'!$AK:$AK,@'Summary'!$B:$B,'Order Data'!$BL:$BL,'Summary'!$T$1),"-")

Dax Query: Dedicated Created To Allocated = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Order_Data[Created to Allocated]), Order_Data[Store Tag]="Dedicated")

All the tables are properly into Power Bi Desktop Application. Even I have refreshed the required tables in Visual Studio by going into "Table Properties" and validating it. But here is the catch when I run the SQL query in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) the data is there in the column but not showing up in Visual Studio 2019.

**Power Bi Version - Version: 2.116.966.0 64-bit (April 2023)**

**Visual Studio Version - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.11.17**

As I am new to this data analytics field, it's a humble request to anyone out there to help me.

**Thank You very much in advance**